# Drawing a hasse diagram of a poset.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

I have the poset $(\{1,2,3,4,5,6,8,15\}, |)$, where $|$ denotes divisibility

and was able to come up with the Hasse diagram [image]

I feel like I had multiple options to connect the $8$ too as well as the $6$. This is my first hasse diagram and I just wanted to post to make sure I did it correctly.

Comment: You are missing two edges there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, you have it upside-down: $1$ is the minimum element and should be at the bottom. Apart from that it’s just missing two lines: there should be a line from $2$ to $6$: $2$ is a divisor of $6$, and there is nothing between them (as $4$, for instance, is between $2$ and $8$). Similarly, there should be a line from $3$ to $15$. Everything else is fine: you have no superfluous lines.